# probability distributions 1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose you test 100 units, randomly sampled from larger batch of 1000 units known to
have 50 defectives.  What is the probability that you will find exactly 5 defectives among
your 100 units?

My attempt

A={5 defectives in 100}

B={50 defectives in 1000}

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)*P(A)}{P(B)}$

$P(A|B)$=$\frac{\binom{900}{45}(.05^{45})(.95^{855}) * \binom{100}{5}(.05^{95})(.95^{95})}{\binom{1000}{50}(.05^{50})(.95^{950})}$

$P(A|B)$=.1897

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You came up with the right value, it looks like, but I'm not sure I can exactly parse your approach.  It is most directly treated as a hypergeometric distribution: Essentially, consider that you are choosing a sample of size $100$ out of a population of size $1000$.

In addition, the sample of size $100$ must contain $5$ defective units (chosen out of a population of $50$) and $95$ non-defective units (chosen out of a population of $950$).  The entire expression, therefore, is

$$
\frac{\binom{50}{5}\binom{950}{95}}{\binom{1000}{100}} \doteq 0.18972
$$